# jquery tokeninput. Backspace doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, jquery, backspace

I'm using jquery tokeninput plug-in.

After added a new token there is not option to delete it using backspace in virtual keyword on android.

In browser or iphone is possible to delete the item pressing backspace.

Basically the `.keydown()` function is never trigger with .

I tried to add `.onkeypress()` and `.onkeyup(`) but never were trigger.

The tokeninput also bind the keyup, keydown to resize the input field

```
.bind("keyup keydown blur update", resize_input)
```

But the resize_input function in never trigger with backspace.

It looks like backspace doesn't work in empty input field in android.

Any ideas?